# How to get traceback in http://locust.io/

Tags: python-2.7, traceback, locust

How to get traceback in http://locust.io/

When i run

```
locust -f locustfile.py --host==http://www.test.com
```

output result displayed in `localhost:8089` port

Now i am seeing the error message for failure requests. i also want to get the traceback when failures occurs in failures tab.

see screenshot for failure tab.[image: locust failure]

How can i see the traceback in failures tab.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can see error messages in the GUI. However you can see error messages in `stderr` or you can alternatively specify `--logfile` option to Locust to pump log messages into a file.  Set `--loglevel` to `DEBUG` for the highest verbosity.